# Not setting variable in class

Tags: php, class

I'll be damned if I can work this out, I've looked at it for too long and probably missing something obvious.

The variable table and order are not setting, and it's not pushing the field in an array. Can anyone spot anything here?

Page

```
<?php
    $table = new table;
    $table->table = "db_firstaid";
    $table->order = "aid_date";
    $table->field("aid_id","false",NULL);
    $table->field("aid_patient","true","[F]");
    $table->field("aid_aider","true","[F]");
    $table->field("aid_date","false","[F]");
    $table->field("aid_time","false","[F]");
    $table->table();
?>
```

Class

```
<?php
    class table{

    /* Connect */
    private $salt   = '#######'
    private $user   = '#######'
    private $pass   = '#######'
    private $host   = '#######'
    private $data   = '#######'
    private $db = '';
    private $link   = NULL;
    private function connect(){
        $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
        if(!$this->link){
            die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">notyfy({text:'Error, could not connect to server.',type:'error',timeout:7000,});</script>");
        }
        $this->db = mysql_select_db($this->data,$this->link);
        if(!$this->db){
            die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">notyfy({text:'Error, could not connect to database.',type:'error',timeout:7000,});</script>");
        }
    }   
    private function disconnect(){
        mysql_close($this->link);
    }

    /* Push fields into array */
    private $fields = array();
    public function field($f,$aes,$t){
        return $this->fields[] = array($f,$aes,$t);
    }

    /* Compile SQL string */
    public  $table  = '';
    public  $order  = '';
    private $sql    = '';
    private function genSQL(){
        foreach($this->fields as $f){
            if($f[1] == 'true'){
                $this->sql = $this->sql . "AES_DECRYPT(".$f[0].",'[SALT]') AS ".$f[0].", ";
            }else{
                $this->sql = $this->sql . $f[0].", ";
            }
        }
        $this->sql = substr($this->sql,0,-1);
        $this->sql = "SELECT ".$this->sql." FROM ".$this->table." ORDER BY ".$this->order;
    }

    /* Query Database */
    private $result = '';
    private $number = '';
    private function query(){
        $this->genSQL();
        $this->result = mysql_query($this->sql,$this->link) or die(mysql_error());
        $this->number = mysql_num_rows($this->result);
    }

    /* Echo Table */
    public function table(){
        $this->connect();
        $this->query();
        if($this->number > 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->result)){
                echo "<tr class=\"selectable\">";

                //Ignore this bit, yet to build.    

                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        $this->disconnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging at all?

Comment: how do you know they are not setting?

Comment: @rid oops. bump my last comment though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your suggestions.

I've got it working now, the php fails on the class and function being called 'table' so I've renamed the function to 'genTable' and left the class as 'table' and it's now behaving.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, try appending some `;` where they are needed. Namely the interface variables you declare at the beginning of your `table` class.

As **rid** has pointed out, PHP may be silently failing on a parsing error.

In case you didn't know, all statements in PHP should be appended with the `;` character.

Obviously, this may not actually be the code you are using. Those hash values would be a pretty major security flaw. ;-)

Comment: @rid your signature fine-combing is cute, but I'm not going to get into a big semantic debate over this...

Comment: Hi, the ; is there in the actual code, I accidentally deleted them hashing out the values for the forum.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
  $db_table = "db_firstaid";
  $order = "aid_date";

  $table = new table($db_table, $order);
```

then in your class, use a constructor like this:

```
public  $table  = '';
public  $order  = '';
private $sql    = '';

public function __constructor($table, $order){
    $this->table = $table;
    $this->order = $order;
}
```

<del>Basically you are not setting the table and order values any where in your class but trying to use the values.</del>

UPDATE: The OP is indeed setting the values so this answer is just another way of doing what OP is already doing. Also, based on the comments, the issue could be elsewhere and OP needs to do more debugging it seems.

Comment: Sure he is: `$table->table = "db_firstaid";`. `table` is a public field, same as `order`.